# Streaming non-youtube videos inside android app

Tags: android, video-streaming

Is there a way to stream non-youtube videos(videos that are not uploaded on youtube) inside android app? Similar to amazon, netflix and other video streaming apps? I am developing an app where the videos may not be necessarily available on youtube.

Comment: Do you just need to play the video from the internet?

Comment: Of course there is a way. What specific question do you have about it?

Answer (score 0):

If the video file has a URL, you can pass it to the [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer). You may find the [ExoPlayer library](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) more powerful.

Not all video storage services will have such URL for you. They may require, just like YouTube, a special SDK, and often cost money.